# dot product between scipy sparse matrix and numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the dot product between a scipy sparse matrix and a numpy.ndarray. tensor refers to theano.tensor. X is the sparse matrix and W_hidden is the ndarray. b_hidden is also ndarray.

```
 tensor.tanh(tensor.dot(X,self.W_hidden)+self.b_hidden)
```

However, there are several problems with this line. I cant compute the dot product. Apart from that, it seems like I am not able to add a constant ndarray to a sparse matrix and further more, I cant apply the tanh function. The error that I get is:

```
 TypeError("Cannot convert %s to TensorType" % str_x, type(x))
```

any help as to how I can solve this problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some details on what exactly your objects look like?  Also, could you separate the `dot` operation, the addition, and the `tanh` operation to better drill down on the error?

Comment: w_hidden is a 2 dimensional numpy matrix filled with random numbers. X is only 1 dimensional. It is one row and about 10,000 columns. I have also tried separating the computations. The error ralated to the dot product is the type Error. The error related to addition is that you cant add a constant to a sparse matrix, which does not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across same two problem as yours recently though I was not dealing with any tensor quantities. If you are still looking for some help:

1) make W_hidden and b_hidden as numpy matrices instead of ndarray. For example, if b_hidden is of shape, (n,) then its matrix form would be of shape, (n,1). This would allow it be added to another matrix, whether sparse or not.

2) use * instead of dot as both X and W_hidden are matrices. Btw, what is the shape of W_hidden?

Comment: W_hidden was also a matrix but its shape depended on the user's choice. I was trying to create a neural network and so the user would get to choose how big the network could be.